# Castle - ActiveRecord - Inheritage

Tags: c#, .net, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to avoid creating the same properties in all ActiveRecord classes, so I am coding this:

Have a base class where I have my common properties: `Id`, `Version`, `LastUpdate`, etc...

```
public class IdentityBase<T> : ActiveRecordValidationBase<T> where T : class
```

Then my "child" class would have his own properties and should inherit from my `IdentityBase`.

```
[ActiveRecord("Users")]
public class User : IdentityBase<User>
```

Now I create an object user:

```
User user = new User()
```

and I can call `user.Save()` but I **can't** call `user.FindAll()` and many others public methods....

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ActiveRecord 2.0 , and all methods like Find , and FindAll - are static so try to use

User.FindAll()

insted of

user.FindAll()